# Creating an eggwash with water vs. milk

Tags: breading

In the context of breading meats, is there a difference in how things adhere to one another? What about in regards to the crispiness in the final outcome?

Comment: are you asking about using the milk or water as alternatives to the egg, or mixing them with the egg?

Comment: I'm referring to *with* eggs.

Comment: Okay ... just wondering as I've heard of using cultured buttermilk as a replacement for the eggs, but not regular milk.  The more important bit for adherence is that you don't want too much of any particular dredge.  See https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44128/67 .  (no idea on the crispness, though)