# troubleshooting katsu(Japanese schnitzel) breading falling off

Tags: deep-frying, japanese-cuisine, breading

I tried to make pork/beef katsu.

My recipe is

1. pork loin/shoulder/steak pat dry
2. season & hammer
3. dredge into flour
4. dip into egg + cream/milk mixture
5. dredge into panko
6. let it rest in fridge to absorb the coating
7. fry
8. rest and cut into slices

When I cut at step 8 the bread always come off as I cut.  I tried both cutting with a cleaver, or slicing with a french knife. neither helped.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you shaking off excess flour and egg before moving onto the next stage?  If not, that could be the problem. You might want to check out some of the questions under the tag ‘breading’, such as https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/13721/67

Comment: "Rest in fright" sounds scary;) Rest in *fridge* perhaps?

Comment: be sure to shake off as much flour as possible. loose the cream from the egg-wash, just use egg and milk, and be mindful of the ratio because too much milk means not much egg to bind the crumbs to the meat. personally i find freshly made breadcrumbs (from 2 day old white bread without the crust, and not too fine of course) give a superior finish and sticks much better than panko.

Comment: Without someone watching your exact procedure, it’s difficult to diagnose.  You might be able to pick up what might have gone wrong by watching videos where chefs explain the procedure well.  For Japanese cooking, I recommend ‘Dining with the Chef’, where they have an experienced chef paired with someone who asks them questions about why they’re doing things.  Unfortunately, the posts on YouTube are the 2-minute summaries, not the full episodes, which are only online for a limited time. But Chef Saito made katsu in an episode in July: https://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/ondemand/video/2019266/

Comment: @Joe good video, key points i took away from it was 1. the use of beaten eggs without milk, 2. double frying to ensure cooked through, and 3. not sawing through.